# Change command used by bjam when installing C++ boost library

Tags: boost, bjam, boost-build

I am trying to make the installation of boost library a little bit slower, because there too many calls to gcc in a short time, which increase my CPU temperature to its limit and crashes the system.

So I add this in /etc/site-config.jam

```
using gcc ; ; "sleep 10; g++" ;
```

However, it gives this error:

> $ ./bjam install
>   /etc/site-config.jam:5: syntax error at keyword ;
>   /etc/site-config.jam:5: in load
>   rule sleep 10; g++ unknown in module pch.
>   /tmp/boost_1_40_0/tools/build/v2/kernel/modules.jam:283: in import
>   /tmp/boost_1_40_0/tools/build/v2/tools/gcc.jam:19: in load
>   /tmp/boost_1_40_0/tools/build/v2/kernel/modules.jam:283: in import
>   /tmp/boost_1_40_0/tools/build/v2/build/toolset.jam:37: in toolset.using
>   /tmp/boost_1_40_0/tools/build/v2/build/project.jam:874: in using
>   project-config.jam:12: in modules.load
>   /tmp/boost_1_40_0/tools/build/v2/build-system.jam:241: in load-config
>   /tmp/boost_1_40_0/tools/build/v2/build-system.jam:407: in load-configuration-files
>   /tmp/boost_1_40_0/tools/build/v2/build-system.jam:538: in load
>   /tmp/boost_1_40_0/tools/build/v2/kernel/modules.jam:283: in import
>   /tmp/boost_1_40_0/tools/build/v2/kernel/bootstrap.jam:138: in boost-build
>   /tmp/boost_1_40_0/boost-build.jam:16: in module scope

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me just duplicate the answer I gave on the boost-users mailing list.

Please refer to [gcc setup documentation](http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/bbv2/reference/tools.html#bbv2.reference.tools.compiler.gcc)

The syntax is gives is:

using gcc : [version] : [c++-compile-command] : [compiler options] ;

In other words, you need to have ":" instead of the first and the second ";".